# rosdep not limiting dependencies correctly on ros2 src install

Tags: ros2, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build ROS2 foxy from source on Alpine linux. I have added a lot of rosdep keys into the rosdep distribution files and changed rosdep to use my repository (I am testing it before I make a PR). I am following the Linux install from source instructions except I only want to install ros_base dependencies. The source instructions try to install deps and compile every package. I checked out the ros2/variants package that defines what ros_base actually is and am trying to use that as the 'package'/'stack' to calculate recursively the dependencies. However it keeps suggesting installing irrelevant packages, and gives me errors about packages I don't care about (desktop).

```
bash-5.0# export
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="cfdae4a75db0"
declare -x LANG="C.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
declare -x PWD="/ros2_ws"
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="foxy"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/foxy/share"
declare -x ROS_VARIANT="ros_base"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SKIP_KEYS="console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
declare -x http_proxy="http://172.17.0.2:3142"
bash-5.0# pipenv run rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro ${ROS_DISTRO} --skip-keys "${SKIP_KEYS} desktop" src/ros2/variants/${ROS_VARIANT}
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
desktop: No definition of [rqt_common_plugins] for OS [alpine]
ros2doctor: No definition of [python3-rosdistro-modules] for OS [alpine]
```

To reiterate, the 'src' directory is the all the repos for the foxy distribution.

```
bash-5.0# pipenv run rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro ${ROS_DISTRO} --skip-keys "${SKIP_KEYS} desktop" src/ros2/variants/${ROS_VARIANT}
System dependencies have not been satisfied:
apk spdlog-dev
apk py3-catkin-pkg
apk eigen-dev
apk py3-pytest
apk py3-babeltrace
apk py3-numpy
apk console_bridge-dev
apk tinyxml-dev
apk cmake
apk curl-dev
apk py3-empy
apk qt5-qtbase-dev
apk pkgconf
apk py3-pytest-cov
apk clang
apk py3-lttng
apk py3-lark-parser
apk freetype-dev
apk libx11-dev
apk libxaw-dev
apk libxrandr-dev
apk mesa-dev
apk freetype
apk qt5-qtbase
apk opencv-dev
apk tinyxml2-dev
apk py3-mock
apk uncrustify
apk assimp
apk py3-matplotlib
apk yaml-dev
apk py3-netifaces
apk clang-extra-tools
apk py3-lxml
apk py3-cryptography
apk py3-psutil
apk py3-pydocstyle
apk py3-qt5
apk py3-pycodestyle
apk sqlite-dev
apk openssl
apk cunit-dev
apk py3-mypy
apk py3-pytest-mock
apk py3-flake8
apk tango-icon-theme
apk py3-pydot
apk py3-graphviz
apk py3-pyflakes
apk bullet-dev
apk cppcheck
apk zstd-dev
apk cppunit
apk libxml2-utils
apk log4cxx-dev
ERROR[desktop]: No definition of [rqt_common_plugins] for OS [alpine]
    rosdep key : rqt_common_plugins
    OS name    : alpine
    OS version : 3.12_alpha20200428
    Data:
_is_ros: true
        osx:
         homebrew:
           packages:
           - ros/foxy/rqt_common_plugins
        ubuntu:
         focal:
           apt:
             packages:
             - ros-foxy-rqt-common-plugins
        
ERROR[ros2doctor]: No definition of [python3-rosdistro-modules] for OS [alpine]
    rosdep key : python3-rosdistro-modules
    OS name    : alpine
    OS version : 3.12_alpha20200428
    Data:
debian:
        - python3-rosdistro-modules
        fedora:
        - python3-rosdistro
        gentoo:
        - dev-python/rosdistro
        openembedded:
        - python3-rosdistro@meta-ros
        rhel:
        - python%{python3_pkgversion}-rosdistro
        ubuntu:
        - python3-rosdistro-modules
```

What am I doing wrong that it wont correctly filter down the system dependencies to a recursive search on ros_base?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354825/rosdep-not-limiting-dependencies-correctly-on-ros2-src-install/) by [russkel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55762/russkel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-13**:
So which dependencies do you feel are "irrelevant"?

> To reiterate, the 'src' directory is the all the repos for the foxy distribution.

wouldn't that be the cause of `rosdep` considering many more packages and their dependencies?

`rosdep` doesn't know about any variants (used to be called *metapackages*). It only looks at what you have in your `src` directory, because you add this to your `rosdep` command line: `--from-paths src`. So if that directory contains more than there would be in `ros_base`, you'll get more dependencies.

**Comment by [russkel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55762/russkel/) on 2020-06-13**:
Wouldn't that be counter-intuitive behavior given the last argument provided to the rosdep command?

```
rosdep install <stacks-and-packages>...
```

> So which dependencies do you feel are "irrelevant"?

I don't believe ros_base should bring in mesa-dev, or anything graphical related.

**Comment by [russkel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55762/russkel/) on 2020-06-13**:
**--from-paths          Affects the 'check', 'keys', and 'install' verbs. If
specified the arguments to those verbs will be
considered paths to be searched, acting on all catkin
packages found there in.**

Ah I see, key part being "Acting on all packages found in there". How can I have it so it doesn't act on all the packages? Is the only way trimming back the src folder to only include ros_base packages? How is that done using ros tooling?

If you're installing from src this is actually quite difficult not being able to tell it to just install dependencies for a particular package. It's because we need to use --ignore-src to ignore the packages we are going to compile.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-13**:\

> I don't believe ros_base should bring in mesa-dev, or anything graphical related.

it doesn't, but you have a *full* clone of everything in your `src` space. `--from-paths` overrides whatever selection you give to `rosdep check|install|etc`.

> Is the only way trimming back the src folder to only include ros_base packages?

Well, why clone *all* repositories if you're only interested in a few?

You should be able to generate a `.rosinstall` file with just the packages in `ros_base` using `rosinstall_generator`:

```
rosinstall_generator --deps --tar --rosdistro=foxy ros_base > foxy_ros_base.rosinstall
```

(if you'd like actual clones of the repositories, don't add `--tar`)

Then use `wstool` or `vcstool` to seed a workspace:

```
mkdir -p foxy_ros_base_ws/src
cd foxy_ros_base_ws/src
vcs import < /path/to/foxy_ros_base.rosinstall
```

Then you can use the command line you show to figure out the dependencies of `ros_base`.

**Comment by [russkel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55762/russkel/) on 2020-06-13**:\

> Well, why clone all repositories if you're only interested in a few?

Documentation makes no mention of rosinstall, only cloning all using ros2.repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As became clearer in the comments, the OP had a full clone of all ROS 2 packages in the `src` space of the workspace.

As `rosdep` was invoked with the `--from-paths` option and given the `src` space as the path, `rosdep` correctly checked each and every package in the `src` space for dependencies, which resulted in dependencies being listed as missing which would normally not show up when only `ros_base` would be considered.

Afaik there is no way to "limit dependencies" with `rosdep`, so to achieve what the OP wants (ie: check dependencies for just the packages contained in `ros_base`), a workspace with *just* the packages in `ros_base` would have to be created.

Using `rosinstall_generator`, this should be possible:

```
rosinstall_generator --deps --tar --rosdistro=foxy ros_base > foxy_ros_base.rosinstall
mkdir -p foxy_ros_base_ws/src
cd foxy_ros_base_ws/src
vcs import < /path/to/foxy_ros_base.rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [russkel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55762/russkel/) on 2020-06-13**:
Thanks, I'll give this a shot.

It's a shame rosdep doesn't have colcon's --package-select/ignore/etc filtering abilities...